# Serre-Swan theorem for infinite rank Frechet or Hilbert bundles?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there a version of Serre-Swan theorem for infinite rank Frechet or Hilbert bundles? If it existed, it would imply if $E\to X$ and $F\to X$ are infinite rank Frechet or Hilbert bundles over a smooth compact manifold $X$, then $E\cong F$ if and only if $\Gamma(X, E)\cong\Gamma(X, F)$.

(I posted this question about half an hour ago, but don't know why it disappeared. So I am posting it again.)

Edit: I just found that my post did not disappear. I first posted this one on math stackexchange but I thought I did it on mathoverflow. That's why I didn't see my first post here. Well...

Comment: (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert bundles over compact spaces are all trivializable because $U(H)$ is contractible, a theorem of Kuiper. So I suppose the answer to your question is yes, for unexciting reasons.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes. The group U(H) is contractible, so the answer is yes. Actually, the structure group of the class of Hilbert bundles I have in mind is actually a subgroup of U(H), which is not contractible.

Comment: Which subgroup then?

Comment: @ThomasRot Actually the class infinite rank bundles I have in mind comes from the setup of the Atiyah-Singer family index theorem. Let $\pi:X\to B$ be a smooth fiber bundle with typical fiber $Z$. Let $E\to X$ be a finite rank complex vector bundle. The structure group of the infinite rank Frechet bundle $p:\pi_*E\to B$ is $\textrm{Diff}(Z, E)$, consisting of pairs $(f, \phi)$ of maps, where $\phi:Z\to Z$ and $f:E\to E$ is linear on the fibers satisfying $p\circ f=\phi\circ p$.